# Adding days in JavaScript returns crazy values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add any amount of days to a given date with this code

```js
$("body").change(".editField", function() {
  var startDate = new Date(Date.now());
  var addedDays = $("#daysAdded").val();
  var calculatedDate = addDays(startDate, addedDays);
  console.log(addedDays);
  console.log(calculatedDate)
  $("#dayResult").val(calculatedDate.toISOString().split("T")[0]);
});
function addDays(date, days) {
  var result = new Date(date);
  result.setDate(result.getDate() + days);
  return result;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type='number' id='daysAdded' class='editField'>
<input type='text' id='dayResult'>
```

Link to JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gv4qswjf/

The problem - no matter what start date you are putting in:

- As soon as you ADD 1, the calculated date jumps to a different year
  (in my case March 2020).
- Then it works fine for a bit...
- As soon as you ADD 10, the calculated date jumps to year 2027.
- Then it works fine for a bit...
- As soon as you ADD 100, the calculated date jumps to year 2069.

Plus SUBTRACTION doesn't work at all!

What is going on?
I haven't found anything about such problem, but for me it occurs in Chrome, Firefox, Edge...

I also tried different jQuery versions (see code above: 1.12, see JSFiddle: 3.3).

Comment: You need to `parseInt(days, 10)` before adding.  The `val()` is a string

Comment: Also consider what will happen [if you `setDate()` to a day that does not exist in the month](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When geting the value of input parse it to Integer using `parseInt()` this will solve your problem

```js
$("body").change(".editField", function() {
  var startDate = new Date(Date.now());
  var addedDays = parseInt($("#daysAdded").val());
  var calculatedDate = addDays(startDate, addedDays);
  console.log(addedDays);
  console.log(calculatedDate)
  $("#dayResult").val(calculatedDate.toISOString().split("T")[0]);
});

function addDays(date, days) {
  var result = new Date(date);
  result.setDate(result.getDate() + days);
  return result;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type='number' id='daysAdded' class='editField'>
<input type='text' id='dayResult'>
```

Comment: Giving myself a facepalm right now! :-)
This solution is so easy and solved it right away! Thank you so much!
I expected the input field type "number" to just return integers right away!